# Colimits of algebras of an endofunctor

Tags: ct.category-theory, limits-and-colimits, alternative-proof, presentable-categories

I try to understand a proof in Adamek-Rosicky's book "Locally presentable and accessible categories", Cambridge University Press 1994. In Corollary 2.75 (p. 121) it is proven that the category $\mathbf{Alg}(T)$  of algebras of an endofunctor $T : \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{C}$ of an accessible category is again accessible. Then the Remark after it argues that $\mathbf{Alg}(T)$ is actually $\lambda$-presentable if $\mathcal{C}$ is $\lambda$-presentable and $T$ is $\lambda$-accessible.

But nothing is said about the existence of colimits. It is only mentioned that free $T$-algebras exist, and with these we can construct a strong generating system consisting of $\lambda$-presentable objects. But this does not produce colimits, right? I have checked that this remark does not appear in the [corrections](http://www.iti.cs.tu-bs.de/~adamek/corrections.pdf) to the book.

Another issue is that the existence of free $T$-algebras is proven via the Adjoint Functor Theorem 1.66, which has only been stated and proven for $\lambda$-presentable categories. This seems to be circular, right?

I think that instead we can use Corollary 2.47 which says a complete $\lambda$-accessible category is already cocomplete, and hence a $\lambda$-presentable category. And $\mathbf{Alg}(T)$ is complete simply because $\mathcal{C}$ is complete.

Comment: Haven't you answered your own question in the final paragraph?

Comment: Yes, but I wanted to make sure that I haven't misunderstood the proof. Maybe it is correct after all. Or did the authors really have Corollary 2.47 in mind without mentioning it?

Comment: I believe you understood correctly. It may be they figured the reader who had gotten thus far in the text would readily supply that argument anyway (but I would agree with you: better safe than sorry).

Comment: I agree that the argument as given is at best highly misleading.  There is a proof that proceeds by constructing free $T$-algebras and colimits of $T$-algebras, but I think one would have to give an explicit construction, since as you say their adjoint functor theorem is only stated for categories already known to be locally presentable.

Comment: @MikeShulman: Thank you. Can you say more about that proof? I think that at some point I will need explicit descriptions of the colimits.

Comment: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/transfinite+construction+of+free+algebras

Comment: @MikeShulman: I already knew this page. Colimits are constructed as reflections from colimits of the comma category  $T' \downarrow \mathcal{C}$, where $T'$ is the free monad on $T$ (which is constructed by a transfinite process). But how do the colimits in this comma category look like? This is not clear since $T'$ is not cocontinuous. (I know the abstract results which show that this comma category is cocomplete.)

Comment: I think the colimit of a diagram $(T A_i \to B_i)$ in $T/C$ consists of $A_\infty = \mathrm{colim}_i A_i$ and $B_\infty = $ the pushout of $T A_\infty$ and $\mathrm{colim}_i B_i$ under $\mathrm{colim}_i T A_i$, with the obvious induced morphism.